# How to get response body in Spring Gateway

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud-gateway

I'm working with spring cloud gateway filters and need to get response body to log it.
I understand that it's problematic, as spring gateway is built on spring reactor, but nevertheless I'm looking for any way to do this.

Have global filter, code:

```
import org.reactivestreams.Publisher;
import org.reactivestreams.Subscriber;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.GatewayFilter;
import org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.GatewayFilterChain;
import org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.GlobalFilter;
import org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.NettyWriteResponseFilter;
import org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.factory.rewrite.ModifyResponseBodyGatewayFilterFactory;
import org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.factory.rewrite.RewriteFunction;
import org.springframework.cloud.gateway.support.ServerWebExchangeUtils;
import org.springframework.core.Ordered;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.server.ServerWebExchange;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

@Component
public class BodyRewrite implements RewriteFunction<byte[], byte[]> {

    @Override
    public Publisher<byte[]> apply(ServerWebExchange exchange, byte[] body) {
        System.out.println("-------------------------");
        System.out.println("       APPLY METHOD");
        System.out.println("-------------------------");
        String originalBody = body==null?"":new String(body);
        if (!ServerWebExchangeUtils.isAlreadyRouted(exchange)) {
            return Mono.just(originalBody.getBytes());
        } else {
            System.out.println("RESPONSE: " + originalBody);
        }

        return new Publisher<byte[]>() {
            @Override
            public void subscribe(Subscriber<? super byte[]> subscriber) {
                
            }
        };
    }
}

@Component
class ModifyResponseBodyFilter implements GlobalFilter, Ordered {
    @Autowired
    private ModifyResponseBodyGatewayFilterFactory modifyResponseBodyGatewayFilterFactory;
    @Autowired
    private BodyRewrite bodyRewrite;

    @Override
    public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, GatewayFilterChain chain) {
        System.out.println("---------------------------");
        System.out.println("       GLOBAL FILTER");
        System.out.println("---------------------------");
        GatewayFilter delegate=modifyResponseBodyGatewayFilterFactory.apply(new ModifyResponseBodyGatewayFilterFactory.Config()
                .setRewriteFunction(byte[].class, byte[].class, bodyRewrite));
        return delegate.filter(exchange, chain);
    }

    @Override
    public int getOrder() {
        return NettyWriteResponseFilter.WRITE_RESPONSE_FILTER_ORDER-1;
    }
```

In the console I only get this output about 30 times in a row and no output with phrase "APPLY METHOD".

```
---------------------------
       GLOBAL FILTER
---------------------------
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

im a rookie,both in English and Programing.
here is a way but may not elegant:
create a modifyResponseBodyFilter with the ModifyResponseBodyGatewayFilterFactory, and implement the RewriteFunction.

```
public class BodyRewrite implements RewriteFunction<byte[], byte[]> {
    @Override
    public Publisher<byte[]> apply(ServerWebExchange exchange, byte[] body) {
        String originalBody = body==null?"":new String(body);
        if (!ServerWebExchangeUtils.isAlreadyRouted(exchange)) {
            return Mono.just(originalBody.getBytes());
        } else {
        // its the reponse body when already routed
        }
    }
}

public class ModifyResponseBodyFilter implements GlobalFilter, Ordered {
    @Autowired
    private ModifyResponseBodyGatewayFilterFactory modifyResponseBodyGatewayFilterFactory;
    @Autowired
    private BodyRewrite bodyRewrite;

    @Override
    public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, GatewayFilterChain chain) {
        GatewayFilter delegate=modifyResponseBodyGatewayFilterFactory.apply(new ModifyResponseBodyGatewayFilterFactory.Config()
                .setRewriteFunction(byte[].class, byte[].class, bodyRewrite));
        return delegate.filter(exchange, chain);
    }

    @Override
    public int getOrder() {
        return NettyWriteResponseFilter.WRITE_RESPONSE_FILTER_ORDER-1;
    }
}
```

Comment: and what should I write in else clause of apply method?

Comment: you can just log the 'originalBody'

Comment: have error "The dependencies of some of the beans in the application context form a cycle:" I added picture in description.

Comment: im sorry ,i cannot see ht picture ,in China.can you paste your code?by the way,the code i pasted above is ok after testing.           you can try to make the relation of the dependencies clear.

Comment: I fixed error, and it doesn't call apply method, so doesn't get response body, am I doing something wrong, or you didn't try this code?

Comment: yes，im sure the code works well in my project。hava you done that defining beans of the two classes by add annotations of Component or Bean in a configuration，which i omitted above？

Comment: I changed description and now it fully shows my implementation of your code and output

Comment: the apply method is executed after NettyWriteReponseFilter,try to debug it.

Comment: I guess you have made a mistake in other code. The method ModifyResponseBodyFilter#filter executes early,then many other filters execute. While the method BodyRewrite#apply executes after  the response code of NettyWriteReponseFilter,try to debug if you have entered into the response code of NettyWriteReponseFilter. Another way if to debug one filter by another，to find which filter has throw an exception.

Comment: It is working!!!! Thank you very much. How did it happen that you said you are a rookie but still you know so much about spring gateway and working with bytes?

Comment: and last question in else statement I should return Mono type, but when I try Mono.never, or Mono.just it doesn't show originalBody in logs. What should I return in else statement?

Comment: I just tried "System.out.println(originalBody); return Mono.just(body);" in else statement,and it works.I said I was a rookie because I had many things to learn, and I didn't know the principles of many technologies while i had worked several years.In fact, i also have a question of spring-cloud-gateway to be answered.