# Read the request body from ServerWebExchange Spring cloud gateway

Tags: reactive-programming, spring-cloud-gateway

I am trying to read the request body data from ServerWebExchange in Spring Cloud Gateway. can anyone please help me how to do this.

Also why this simple task is so difficult in reactive programming.

Answer (score 0):

It's the same as reading or modifying the response body.
see: `ModifyRequestBodyGatewayFilterFactory` and `ModifyResponseBodyGatewayFilterFactory`

[How to get response body in Spring Gateway](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64458684/14489768)